# How to call a jQuery function from a for-loop in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt, foreach

so this may be a unique question

I have this XSL for-each loop which generates 3 strings Music, TV, Comedy

**The HTML (and my javascript attempt)** *Uncaught SyntaxError*

```
<div id="rgt" style="position:absolute; height:1px; visibility:hidden;">
    <xsl:for-each select="$GenreTypes/item">
        <div id="rgt-{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('title',.)" /><!-- Spits out Music, TV, Comedy -->

            <!-- Where I'm trying to call my function to add titles to an Array -->
            <script type="text/javascript">$.addRelatedGenres('{sc:fld('title',.)}');</script>
         </div>
     </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

Basically I'm needing to capture these values into an Array in jQuery. I am 'printing' out the strings I need to a hidden div, as each string is being 'printed' by the for-each loop, I want to call my jQuery function and add each string to the Array.

**My jQuery function**

```
function addRelatedGenres(rgt_name) {
    console.log(rgt_name);
}
```

So far I'm getting syntax errors, not sure how to call a Javascript / jQuery function from the page that isn't an onClick or dependant on the page url (everything happens on 1 page, so there is no new pages, just divs that get unhidden and hidden).

Perhaps there's a better way to do this?

Thanks for taking a peek! :)

Comment: Your function is not a "jQuery function".  It's javascript.  Firstly you need to remove the `$.` from before the call.

Comment: Ah sweet that was it! Could you post this as a question and I'll 'Check' it :)

Comment: Glad to help - Will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not a "jQuery function" - it's javascript. You need to remove the `$.` from before the call.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$.addRelatedGenres('{sc:fld('title',.)}');</script>
```

be

```
<script type="text/javascript">$.addRelatedGenres('<xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('title',.)" />');</script>
```

?

IIRR, the {   } syntax only works in attributes.

Comment: I tried that but it spits out this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)} has no method 'addRelatedGenres' If I use $(). I get this error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addRelatedGenres'